# How to eliminate the the light edge after turning part of the picture into black&white? (Selective-color)

Tags: photoshop, black-and-white, selective-color

I tried to use the selective-color technique in the following photo. I added a black&white filter layer with the girl masked. However the right margin of the girl's hand turned out to be white, while there's no additional light source from that direction.

The original photo is posted below.

I have to admit that there's a little bit white on the margin in the original photo. However the white is not that heavy. So I think it must be the `black&white` that worsened that margin.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Update your mask.  It's hard to tell from the low res copy you posted, but it appears that the black and white mask is bleeding on to the hand by a little bit.

Comment: It's not the bleed. And I even tried to overflow the mask as well as inflow to include and exclude that edge. However the edge is still there and seems to be different in tone rather than color from the nearby pixels.

Comment: @SolessChong - can you post 100% crops before and after of that area specifically then?  That might help identify what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the mask seems to be off a bit on the hand and the coat...

Secondly, you are editing probably in RGB and not in L*a*b. These type of effects are best done in luminosity-based color spaces, otherwise mixing RGB without preserving luminosity can create this type of luminosity transformation between layers. (Note in general: transparency between layers is **not** luminosity-preserving if you are not in L*a*b!)

Thirdly, on your images, sharpening and JPEG also enhances perceivable edges, and there is a lot of JPEG noise around that hand. JPEG does not really like B&W...

But without a full resolution crop of that hand area (in PNG! :-)), I cannot tell more.

BTW: I suggest using Feather in this case during masking...